# Removing a Link From All Website Pages

Tags: awk, replace, sed, edit

I'm trying to remove a particular link from all the website pages at once. At the bottom of each page, this link appears and it is no longer necessary, so I'd like to remove it. I don't want to go through thousands of files to remove it manually. I'm using Notepad++ to edit these files. Is there a way to remove the link from all the files at once?

Comment: Well you know PHP right? Do some str_replace on all your files.

Comment: You could use `sed` or `awk` I'd think. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files If notepad++ is your only option I guess open all the files and do a find/replace on all open files?

Comment: This is not a php question.

Comment: I think the OP is using windows (he's using notepad++), so sed might not be readily available. [Here's](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) where you can get sed on Windows.

Comment: Possibly, if the user is using a server that runs linux/unix though they can do it there. I think OP is editing on their personal machine via FTP.

Comment: I'd hope the OP has access to a command line. If it's a freehost that only allows ftp access, then using sed/awk is out of the question (at least not using the remote host, you can still use sed/awk on windows if you download the correct tools).

Comment: Yes this is absolutely trivial using UNIX tools. [edit] your question to clarify your requirements (are you removing a line number or a line matching a string or a line matching a regexp or something else?) and provide concise, testable sample input and expected output. If you're on Windows then a) condolences and b) install cygwin ASAP to run the tools from.

Answer (score 0):

Each basic IDE got an replace all option. I use PhpStorm for stuff like this, but you can also install free IDEs like Netbeans. The installation cost you just a few minuts, so when there are a lot of files which need to edit, this is the best way.

Comment: Opening thousands of files in not the best way.

Comment: You dont need to open them, the option is called 'Replace in path'. Then you just write your 'Text to find' and the 'Replace with'.

Comment: PhpStorm you can also get as trial, so just do the job and then remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Install cygwin then run:

```
find something -exec sed -i '$d' \;
```

and it's done. `something` is the root directory under which your files live plus some info to identify them (e.g. *.html or *.php or whatever).

Note - the above is based on my guessing what your question means. Further details and examples would clear up any misunderstanding.